# Django Password Change Form giving wrong POST value for Old Password of Admin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have created a link to the Password Change Form using:

```
<a href="{% url 'web_password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a>
```

And included it in urls.py as:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

url(r'^password_change', auth_views.password_change, {"template_name": "web/password_change_form.html"}, name='web_password_change'),
```

My Password Change Form is :

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n static bootstrapped_goodies_tags %}
{% load url from future %}
{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/forms.css" %}" />{% endblock %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="{% url 'web_index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a></li>
<li>{% trans 'Password change' %}</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}{% trans 'Password change' %}{% endblock %}
{% block content_title %}<a class="navbar-brand">{% trans 'Password change' %}</a>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}<div id="content-main">

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {% if form.errors.items|length == 1 %}{% trans "Please correct the error below." %}{% else %}{% trans "Please correct the errors below." %}{% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}

<div class="alert alert-info">{% trans "Please enter your old password, for security's sake, and then enter your new password twice so we can verify you typed it in correctly." %}</div>

<fieldset class="_module _aligned wide">

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        {{ form.old_password.label_tag }}
    </div>
    <div class="controls col-sm-10">
        {% dab_field_rendering form.old_password %}
        {% if form.old_password.errors %}<span class="text-danger">{{ form.old_password.errors|striptags }}</span>{% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        {{ form.new_password1.label_tag }}
    </div>
    <div class="controls col-sm-10">
        {% dab_field_rendering form.new_password1 %}
        {% if form.new_password1.errors %} <span class="text-danger">{{ form.new_password1.errors|striptags }}</span>{% endif %}
        {% if form.new_password1.help_text %}<span class="text-info">{{ form.new_password1.help_text }}</span>{% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        {{ form.new_password2.label_tag }}
    </div>
    <div class="controls col-sm-10">
        {% dab_field_rendering form.new_password2 %}
        {% if form.new_password2.errors %} <span class="text-danger">{{ form.new_password2.errors|striptags }}</span>{% endif %}
        {% if form.new_password2.help_text %}<span class="text-info">{{ form.new_password2.help_text }}</span>{% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

</fieldset>

<div class="form-actions">
    <div class="controls col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Change my password' %}" class="default btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("id_old_password").focus();</script>
</form></div>

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is :
It works for all web users, but if I login as admin and then change the password, say if the original password is:'admin'...Now I change it to '1234', it works and I can login again.

But when I again go to change_password and try to change from '1234' to something else, it gives 'Incorrect Old Password'.

On debugging, I found that the POST request received has the old_password field value as 'admin' while I have typed '1234'.

When I tried to add another field on the html page and updated the old_password section as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        {{ form.old_password.label_tag }}
    </div>
    <div class="controls col-sm-10">
        {% dab_field_rendering form.old_password %}
        {{ form.old_password }}
        {% if form.old_password.errors %}<span class="text-danger">{{ form.old_password.errors|striptags }}</span>{% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly fine and receives the correct request, but I can't ask user to enter the old password two times.

Comment: What is `dab_field_rendering`?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of that ... actually I have copied this template from django admin's change password template itself ... I tried to search for its meaning and found out its something related to applying css class but couldn't find more information.